# PyMongo: how to get all objects that match any of possible filters?

Tags: pymongo, flask-pymongo

I have a list of "usernames" as an array, and a list of posts in a mongodb collection with an "author" variable. I want to get all objects from the collection whose author is one of the usernames in the array.

so if:

Collection:
{
"author": "tim"
},
{
"author": "bob"
},
{
"author": "jon"
}

following = ["tim", "jon"]

then i only want to get the posts by tim and jon

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer; it should be:

```
following = ["tim", "jon"]
mongo.db.posts.find({"author": {"$in": following}})
```

This will only get posts where the author is `tim` or `jon`.